# How to ignore sql column names via Python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to run a sql query via python but every time I remove the two last lines of code I get an error which I don't understand  - The code below is which I am trying to run, and these are the lines of code which I erased:

1 - `columnNames = [n.replace('b','') for n in list(results.columns.values)]`

2 - `results.columns = columnNames`

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=XXX",autocommit=True)
sql = "select b.* from X.Y a inner join X.X b where a.tradeid = b.tradeid where a.productmaintypeid = 'InterestRateCapFloor' limit 10"
results = pandas.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
```

Error Message

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select b.* from trade.trades a inner join trade.legs b where a.tradeid = b.tradeid where a.productmaintypeid = 'InterestRateCapFloor' limit 10': ('HY000', "[HY000] [Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:83 missing EOF at 'where' near 'tradeid' (80) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: we need a [MCVE]

Comment: Could we also see the error? Maybe even the code? Try to get us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: and properly formatted code :)

Comment: I am going to add the proper code

Comment: DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select b.* from trade.trades a inner join trade.legs b where a.tradeid = b.tradeid where a.productmaintypeid = 'InterestRateCapFloor' limit 10': ('HY000', "[HY000] [Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:83 missing EOF at 'where' near 'tradeid' (80) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: Apologies for the poor code.  Does the error message above helps?

Comment: Sure will. I added it to the question in an edit. Im not a panda's expert so I would wait for someone to take a peak at the question and then they can help more.

Comment: Are you saying you have a SQL error only when you add two lines of Python code *after* the sql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your SQL query to

```
select b.* from trade.trades a inner join trade.legs b where a.tradeid = b.tradeid AND a.productmaintypeid = 'InterestRateCapFloor' limit 10
```

essentially you need to remove extra where.

Comment: Also check if your database support limit keyword.

Comment: Hi All, thanks very much for your help. you were right, it was just a silly sql error rather than a python error. sorted now! with or without replace function